# Extract elements from ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

My Observable list looks like this :  [AR | Argentina | 2 |

```
AU | Australia | 3 | 
BE | Belgium | 1 | 
BR | Brazil | 2 | 
CA | Canada | 2 | 
CH | Switzerland | 1 | 
CN | China | 3 | 
DE | Germany | 1 | 
DK | Denmark | 1 | 
EG | Egypt | 4 | 
FR | France | 1 | 
IL | Israel | 4 | 
IN | India | 3 | 
IT | Italy | 1 | 
JP | Japan | 3 | 
KW | Kuwait | 4 | 
ML | Malaysia | 3 | 
MX | Mexico | 2 | 
NG | Nigeria | 4 | 
NL | Netherlands | 1 | 
SG | Singapore | 3 | 
UK | United Kingdom | 1 | 
US | United States of America | 2 | 
ZM | Zambia | 4 | 
ZW | Zimbabwe | 4 | 
]
```

I would like to extract each these words and insert them in tableColumn so it would look like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufmzL.jpg

Comment: Start by making a `Country` class and organizing your data into an `ObservableList<Country>`

Comment: Just to add to what @James_D has said, the class, `Country` will have attributes (code, name, score) to correspond to the three values of each row.